# Как подсчитать кол-во чисел в диапазоне 1-21, которые заканчиваются на 2?

Tags: python

Как подсчитать кол-во чисел в диапазоне 1-21, которые заканчиваются на 2?

Comment: Добрый день, а как Вы пробовали решить задачу? С чем конкретно возникли сложности?

Comment: @wairua Да, пробовал. Возникли трудности конкретно с нахождением числа. Нужно найти 2 и 12. Как найти я не понимаю

Comment: @Wairua Смотрите-ка, не так все однозначно, вот я это отредактировал и вопрос стал он-топик (практически).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>60</s> <s>45</s> 37 bytes

-15 cпасибо Эникейщику

-8 cпасибо [Grimmy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6484/grimmy)

```python
print(sum(i%10==1for i in range(21)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzv6AoM69Eo7g0VyNT1dDA1tYwLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDyFBTU/P/fwA)

Comment: print(2) //и ещё букв

Comment: @AlexeyTen Если две программы дают одинаковые результаты, еще не значит, что они обе решают задачу.

Comment: @Эникейщик вопрос был «посчитать». Их два

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ваша прога выводит 2, а не считает.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а, точно!

Comment: Ну на идиотский вопрос идиотский ответ. Если б в вопросе было хотя бы от 1 до N, а не до 21

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я бы ему вопрос еще немного переделал, но так нельзя.

Comment: Покороче: print(len([i for i in range(22) if i%10==2]))

Comment: @Эникейщик  [Может кто придумает еще покороче.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200363/find-the-number-of-integers-in-the-range-from-1-to-n-that-ends-with-2)

Comment: @Эникейщик 37 bytes:`print(sum(i%10==1for i in range(21)))`

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica print(2) выводит значение, которое было кем-то *посчитано*, а значит [всё честно](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png) :)

Comment: `print(1+1)` - теперь _считает._ // cc @AlexeyTen

Comment: Почему `==1`? А, всё, уже понял, прикольно :)

Comment: можно чуть короче: `print(21//10)` ;)